# Looking for a children's mystery novel set in south africa

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a children's mystery novel set in South Africa, of which I remember several details.  I should say up front that the novel I am looking for is **not** Phyllis Whitney's "Secret of the Tiger's Eye", despite some similarities.

I remember the following details.  (It is possible that I've conflated details from multiple novels here, but I'm pretty sure these are all from one book):

- The heroes are (I think) three children, all siblings, who are not South African natives.  The oldest child is the protagonist.  They are English speaking and I believe they are white.
- When the children are preparing for their journey to South Africa, they learn about apartheid and are taught to pronounce it as "apart-hate", which the protagonist agrees is an appropriate sounding word.
- One of the children receives a spelling lesson in which he is taught to remember that "there is 'a rat' in 'separate'".
- The youngest child pronounces "dungarees" as "doug-maries".
- There is an adult character, a South African native, who serves as the family's guide to South Africa.  He is called Jojo.
- I'd have read this book probably in the early 1960s.

I seem also to remember that there is a very frightening scene in a cave, but that might be a false memory based on the cave scene in "Secret of the Tiger's Eye".

Googling doesn't seem to help at all with this.  I'll be glad if anyone here can help.

Comment: Great, thanks! I deleted my earlier comments as they're no longer needed, but the welcome I expressed therein remains.